# Gradle can't build Android Project in command line, aapt fails

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have created a basic Android project following [this guide.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle-android/)

Now when I run gradle(version 2.10) in my command line I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
}
```

And here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.hello"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Funny thing is, when I start Android Studio(1.5) and build a test application there it works fine, but doing it in command-line fails. I tried copying the gradle file from AS, to no avail. I checked the installation path, aapt is where it is supposed to be.

I'm quite lost here since I used that very same guide from above a few months ago. Today I updated my Android SDK installation(**EDIT:** I made sure the right revisions are installed) but I can't get anything to build properly.

Let me know if you need more information, I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you show your command line?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. After reinstalling Gradle, I finally got a new error message that told me in plain english what was wrong(it was a problem with my resources).

This is really weird, since I use Archlinux and all other Gradle updates worked fine before.

Thanks anyway to whomever has given this some thought :)